# camera.action.CROP not working as expected

Tags: android

I am struggling with a problem already for few days and I can't figure out any solution, all my researches are done.

I have a simple Camera/Gallery intent followed by a crop intent.

I have encountered 2 problems by now.

1. On Huawei P9 the intent seems to be successful with a toast with the message "Saving picture" but it seems like the crop screen is not finished because nothing happens after.
2. On Samsung Galaxy S8 & S8 plus the image after the crop has bad quality.

My crop method is below:

```
protected void performCrop(File file) {

        // take care of exceptions
        try {
            // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
            // support it)
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", ASPECT_X);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", ASPECT_Y);
//            // indicate output X and Y
//            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
//            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC);
        }
        // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Toast toast = Toast
                    .makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

As you can see I tried different possibilities and solutions, nothing worked. If anyone has any idea how I could solve this, please let me know.

Comment: I suggest you do not use inbuilt Crop action. I have struggled it with a lot and i thing  many people too. There is no guarantee cause there are 100s of devices and 1000s of apps which handles crop intent in their own way . Even if you make it work on some you will left will some others in which it will not work . **Instead of**  it create your own cropper or you can use a third party library for image crop . There are bunch of library available open source for it. In this way you have the all control and it will also work on all of the devices. Does this make sense ?

Comment: Yeah, already started to look up for some libraries. Thank you for the suggestion.